# How to use @ConversationScoped to handle more than one backing bean?

Tags: java, jsf-2, cdi

Java 1.7 / JSF 2 / JPA 2 / Hibernate 4

I have read a number of tutorial and posts about `@ConversationScoped` and in all of them the message is the same: use it when you have many views for **one** backing bean.

However, I have a business process scenario where I have to:

1. Show a number of items in a listing page (supported by a listing backing bean);
2. Show an editing page (supported by **another** backing bean) to edit a particular item of the listing;
3. After the editing is finnished, go back to the listing page that should show the same previous context.

The editing page is complex and have many dependencies that do not make sense to be in the listing backing bean, that's why I prefer to have two backing beans working over two different pages, but in one single business context.

Can that be achieved? What are the steps?

Comment: _use it when you have many views for one backing bean._ where does it state that? Your 1,2,3 are possible, I do these things al the time. In basic ways... ... I fail to see the real problem/question... Sorry... But maybe 'viewscoped'  beans are more suited here... Not sure

Comment: @Kukeltje: *Meanwhile - during the conversation - the client may execute AJAX requests against the bean or navigate to other pages that still reference this same managed bean. In these cases the bean will keep its state across client interactions.*. You will find this in http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-cdi-conversationscoped-example

Comment: @Kukeltje: so, what you say is that you  annotate your backing beans with `@ViewScoped` and simply navigate from one page to the other and when you get back to the first page, its context is preserved?

Comment: As far as I can see, the problem here is that you want to keep the context for the list. However, I don't know what do you mean as 'context'. Is it the order and filtering for the list?

Comment: You meantioned no scope bound to those backing beans, so I will take a blind shot. How about making those backing beans `@Dependent` and injecting them into this `@ConversationScoped` bean? `@ConversationScoped` bean would then be used to restore (set) the state on those pages using information from those dependent beans? (Just to make it clear - a dependent bean has a lifecycle bound to whatever it is injected into, hence here it will exist as long as the conversation does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, I could make it to work. All I had to do was to add the **cdi** button parameter on my edit button. In order to make it to work, my edit button had to be something like this:

```
<p:commandButton title="Edit"
                 action="#{myMB.nextView}"
                 ajax="false">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{bean.id}"/>
    <f:param name="cid" value="#{myMB.conversation.id}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```